# Are untyped and simply typed lambda calculus mutually exclusive?

Tags: logic, computability, lambda-calculus, type-theory

In "Proposition as Types" by Philip Wadler we can read that:

> The **two applications of lambda calculus, to represent computation
>   and to represent logic, are in a sense mutually exclusive.**
>
> If a notion of computation is powerful enough to represent any effectively
>   calculable procedure, then that notion is not powerful enough
>   to solve its own Halting Problem: there is no effectively calculable
>   procedure to determine whether a given effectively calculable
>   procedure terminates.
>
> However, the consistency of Church’s logic
>   based on simply-typed lambda calculus depends on every term having
>   a normal form

In my current interpretation, Wadler is essentially saying that *untyped lambda calculus* is powerful enough to represent any effectively calculable procedure but can't solve its own "Halting problem" (i.e handle self-application). Whereas  *simply typed lambda calculus* can solve it trivially because every term has a form where $\beta$-reduction is not possible (normal form).

I am surprised by the strong wording of Wadler, calling those two "mutually exclusive". Does that mean that *simply typed lambda calculus* cannot represent any effectively calculable procedure or am I missing the point?

Comment: Note spelling: Wadler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is deeper than just a property of the simply typed lambda calculus in particular.

There are plenty of ways to extend the simply types lambda-calculus into something that is useful for computations, without letting go op the types. So it's not just a question of typed versus untyped.

Rather, the point is that *as soon as you have a general way to write an infinite loop* for your computation, "general" meaning that it works no matter which type of value the loop was supposed to have produced if it ever completed, then because of that very fact *every type is inhabited* and as a result the corresponding logic is *inconsistent*.

So there can't ever be any calculus that is *both* useful for expressing arbitrary computations in a natural way, *and* creates a consistent logic through the propositions-as-types principle.

In light of this fundamental incompatibility, it's remarkable how useful and fruitful as a source of ideas for as well logic and programming the correspondence *nevertheless* is.

Comment: So Goedel's system $T$ or Girard/Reynold's system $F$ aren't useful and natural? I think quite a few people would take issue with that.

Comment: @Rob: I moderated the claim slightly. What I meant is they're not universal.

Comment: But still, wearing my software engineer's hat, I'm not sure I would call programming in System F "natural". I know _how_ to do a lot of things there, but not having an explicit recursion facility would still feel awkward.

Comment: Well they say that real programmers can write FORTRAN in any language, but System F tries to give them a really hard challenge!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for your answer! I have a hard time to see what is the relation between "inhabited typed" and "inconsistent logic", could you elaborate on that particular point?

Comment: @ErwanAaron: An inconsistent logic is one that allows a proof of every propoisiton. The propositions-as-types program consists of the ideas that (1) each proposition corresponds to a type, and (2) a (closed) term with a particular type counts as a proof of the proposition that corresponds to the type. Thus, if every type is inhabited (i.e. there is a closed term of that type), it means that every proposition has a proof and thus the corresponding logic will be inconsistent.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks again! That's perfect!!

Comment: What do you think of my answer below? Do I make a valid point, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The simply typed lambda calculus cannot code every algorithm, since every "program" written in it halts.

Comment: But a by definition a  non-terminating computation is not "an effectively calculable procedure" so this class of programs can't be represented in untyped lambda calculus either right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I think I disagree with Philip Wadler's conclusion. We could have a system with two kinds of terms, "total" and "partial". If you're willing to work with partial terms, then you get loops, recursion etc. The total terms wouldn't have this property, but nonetheless there could be a way to go between them. A partial term of type $T$ could feasibly be turned into a total term of type $\mathrm{Maybe} \;T$. And of course, every total term of type $T$ can also be turned into a partial term of type $T$. So the two systems would be interlinked, thereby potentially offering facilities for both logic and computation in one type system.

Comment: "A partial term of type T could feasibly be turned into a total term of type Maybe T" -- that is a lot trickier than you think it is. To begin with, we're leaving the realm of practical computation, because the operation I think you're imagining would need to know whether the computation represented by the "partial" term _ever_ terminates. But that's the least of our worries! Much worse is how to _define_ your operation explicitly, especially in the case where the partial term you apply it to _itself_ contains your "totalization" operator.

Comment: In fact, if the "partial" side of your system looks somewhat like a functional programming language (which was the point, right?) you'd create a paradox if you write: `let rec f(x) = case partialize(totalize(f(x))) of Nothing -> 42 | Just n -> (infinite loop)`. Then `f(5)` ought to terminate if it diverges and diverge if it terminates!

Comment: @HenningMakholm, ahh sorry but I'm afraid I don't understand the notation. Can you describe the program in words, or else link to somewhere that explains the syntax? I've seen Just n in the little Haskell Ive been exposed to, but the rest is a bit mysterious

Comment: I assumed your background was in Haskell because you spoke of "Maybe T". If there another language's syntax you'd prefer?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, well, Python is my current favourite. I learned about the Maybe monad from nLab, not Haskell.

Comment: Okay, I don't think it can be written nicely in Python, so let's try prose. 1) Start with the "partial" term $f(x)$ of type int. 2) Convert to a "total" term of type Maybe int. 3) Convert back to a "partial" term still of type Maybe int. 4) Wrap that in code that looks at the Maybe value and produces $42$ if it sees $*$, but loops forever if it sees an integer. 5) Make the resulting term the definition of the recursive function $f(x)$. 6) Does $f(5)$ terminate or not?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, okay, I take your point. That's definitely a problem. However, I think the right way to resolve this is to allow unrestricted conversion between partial and total terms, while restricting the kinds of expressions that recursion can be applied to. That makes sense from a (classical) set-theoretic point of view. Set-theoretically, every total function $X \rightarrow Y$ can be viewed as a partial function $X \rightarrow Y$ without restriction. And, every partial function $X \rightarrow Y$ can be viewed as a total function $X \rightarrow Y+1$ without restriction.

Comment: So the problem, from this viewpoint, is really overzealous belief in the ability to do recursion, as opposed to issues with `totalize`. To make the resulting system work, I think we'd have to track the use of constructs like `totalize` that interfere with recursive definitions, and very carefully design the rules associated with recursion to only be applicable when constructs like `totalize` aren't mentioned in a problematic way.

Comment: In fact, this fits pretty comfortably with the common set-theoretic experience that not every endofunctor $\mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ has an initial algebra, e.g. $\mathcal{P}$ for example. Assuming initial algebras are a tool for permitting various forms of recursion, and assuming not every endofunctor on $\mathbf{Set}$ has an initial algebra, it's perhaps not too surprising that the ability to do unrestricted recursion is problematic.